# Solving $\int_0^{\infty} x^{d-2} (x^2+1)^{-s/2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I'm redoing some calculations in the book (E. Elizalde, 10 physical applications of spectral zeta functions, 2nd ed., equations 5.36-5.37) for my thesis and can't solve this integral.

$\int_0^{\infty} x^{d-2} (x^2+1)^{-s/2} dx$

Where $d$ is a positive integer and $s$ can be whatever complex number we want that makes this integral convergent. By reverse engineering from the book the solution should  be (unless I dropped some factors)

$\int_0^{\infty} x^{d-2} (x^2+1)^{-s/2} dx=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{d-1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{s-d+1}{2})}{2\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})}$

I tried to merge the three gamma functions into something simpler but can't manage to do so. It doesn't seem to be a binomial coefficient either. Also tried changing variables from $x^2+1$ to $z$ so that I could series expand $(1-z)^{(d-3)/2}$ and while that solves the integral, it leaves us with a very difficult series that seems unrelated to the gamma functions that should appear.

So... I'm pretty lost. Any ideas?

Comment: $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{d-2}}{ (x^2+1)^{s/2}} dx\overset{x^2=y}=\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{y^{d/2-3/2}}{(1+y)^{s/2}}dy$$
And using the following formula to get the result:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}dt=B(x,y)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. By the change of variable
$$
t=\frac{1}{1+x^2}, \quad x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{t}-1}, \quad dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}\left(\frac{1}{t}-1\right)^{-1/2}dt,
$$ one gets
$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^{d-2} (x^2+1)^{-s/2} dx=\int_0^1 t^{s/2-d/2-1/2} (1-t)^{d/2-3/2} \,dt
$$ then one may use the standard [Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).